# I am in AWS Lex 2 using Lambda call another bot from a master bot

Tags: bots, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am creating a Greeter bot then directing from the greeter bot to specific bots.  I need to develop this way as my organization has many bots and distinct departmental bots.

I have tried client.PostText but I am getting an error within the function.

I am using AWS Lex 2 (only one available in Canada) and Lambda to make the call.

I'm not sure what would be best the Greeter invoking the specific the redirecting back to Greeter or the Greeter calling the specific and have the specific answer in the Greeter Bot.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you would like to orchestrate more than one Lex chatbot to provide your customer with assistance across different departments.

An approach that you could use would involve using a Lambda function in front of your Lex bots. This lambda function would need to have some state to recognise between a new and existing customer and direct the customer accordingly.

A new customer would be directed to the Greeter bot and upon fulfilment would then be directed towards the next bot. So the Greeter bot would say hello and ask the customer to select the department that they would like assistance with.

Your lambda function will need to store that information and then start calling the correct bot for the customer's chosen department.